# How to pass vertical line

Tags: hyperref, conditionals, indexing

I have the following problem.  The general idea is to test whether #1 is empty and if it isn't then write vertical line "|" and #1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx,hyperref}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\textindex}[2][]{#2\index{#2%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    % do nothing
   \else
    |#1% 
  \fi}}

\begin{document}
\textindex{Hello} \textindex[textbf]{World}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

`\textindex{word}` should make `word\index{word}` and `\textindex[textbf]{word}` should make `word\index{word|textbf}`.  But in the second case I get `Extra \else` error.  Why?

**EDIT**  Putting vertical line into parentheses `{|}` helps, but parentheses remain in `idx` file.

Comment: `|` has no special meaning: we are going to need more context here.

Comment: @JosephWright OK I added some context.  Somehow "|" makes all the difference.  Without it `\ifx` works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `\ifx\\#1\\` with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,imakeidx,hyperref}
\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand{\textindex}{om}{%
  #2%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\index{#2}}
   {\index{#2|#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\textindex{Hello} \textindex[textbf]{World}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: the command `\textindex` has two arguments, one optional `o` and one mandatory `m`. If the optional argument is passed, that is, `\textindex` is followed by `[...]`, then `#1` has the passed value and makes the conditional `\IfNoValueTF{#1}` false, otherwise it makes true the conditional `\IfNoValueTF{#1}`.

---

If you want to use the `\ifx\\#1\\` method, then it's just a matter of

```
\newcommand\textindex[2][]{%
  #2%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \index{#2}%
  \else
    \index{#2|#1}%
  \fi
}
```

but I don't see why using clumsy code, when better one is available.

Comment: Why not Heiko Oberdieks `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`?

Comment: @Ruben Because `xparse` make us able to dispense with it.

Comment: I like the idea of separating `index` command and `ifx` command (error is obviously due to the fact they are criss-crossed).  Actually after sleeping over, I came to the same idea myself.  Why do you consider that code clumsy?  I always choose solutions without using additional packages.

Comment: @Pygmalion It would be way clumsier if we wanted to have just one `\index` token in the code (Heiko's idea). But it's better, in my opinion, distinguish between “no optional argument” and “empty optional argument”.

Answer (score 3):

The following example works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\textindex}[2][]{#2\index{#2%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    % do nothing
   \else
    |#1% 
  \fi}}

\begin{document}
\textindex{Hello} \textindex[textbf]{World}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

If `|` is active, then `\string` helps:

```
\string|%
```

Note, that I have commented the end of lines to avoid the insertion
of unwanted spaces.

Another more defensive variant:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textindex}[2][]{%
  #2%
  \def\testindex@param{#1}%
  \index{%
    \detokenize{#2}%
    \ifx\testindex@param\@empty
    \else 
      \detokenize{|#1}% 
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

- The test for emptiness is made more robust.
- The expansion of the arguments `#1` and `#2`
  is prevented by e-TeX's `\detokenize`.
  (`\index` would have read its argument verbatim,
  but the definition prevents this.)

Even more defensive for `hyperref`, which needs to parse the contents
of `\index` to find an encap command and disrupting the `\if` construct
in the process:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textindex}[2][]{%
  #2%
  \begingroup
    \def\testindex@param{#1}%
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\index{%
        \detokenize{#2}%
        \ifx\testindex@param\@empty
        \else
          \detokenize{|#1}%
        \fi
      }%
    }%  
  \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textindex{Hello} \textindex[textbf]{World}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The raw index file `.idx`:

```
\indexentry{Hello|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{World|hyperindexformat{\textbf}}{1}
```

Comment: Neither of two suggested solution helped.  I will prepare MWE after all, my current guess is that it has something to do with  `hyperref` package.

Comment: Yes, it is `hyperref` package that makes fuss.   `\detokenize` solves the problem, but `\detokenize` remains in `idx` file.

Comment: @Pygmalion No, `\detokenize` is expandable and will vanish after the expansion of the `\edef` step.